# Retain opacity on mousemove - canvas

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, imagefilter

I am trying to color on some area on the canvas using mouseMove. I am able to retain opacity on a single mouse click. But when I am doing a mousemove, the color opacity is not retained. Tried multiple solutions but nothing worked over. Attaching a fiddle with a sample.

[image]

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xsfLukw/)

```
 ctx.arc(x, y, w, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.filter = 'opacity(30%)';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath()
```

PS: I am using canvas and no scope of svg  in my requirement.

Any Help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The solution is not working in my case, been run into some issues. Any solution on this would be helpful @Kaiido

Comment: Sorry I won't have time right now to help you out. If you wish me to reopen your question (in at least 12hrs for me, but others could do the same), please [edit] it to explain clearly why the solutions there didn't work, and also include in the question itself what you have that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are drawing slowly, so the opacity of a bunch of line segments is adding up as multiple draw calls on top of one another.

If you would prefer an alpha'd line, consider drawing it at 100%, and reducing the `globalalpha` instead. ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha))

Comment: No luck by reducing GlobalApha as well. :(